# sys.path being ignored

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, sys, egg

I have a function to extract an `.egg` file containing python packages such as `boto3`:

```py
# utils.py
def glue_extract_egg_file() -> None:
    package_path = "/tmp/packages"
    # logic to extract the egg file
    sys.path.insert(0, package_path)
    logging.info(f"Updated sys.path with the package path: {sys.path}")
```

Running this function in my main file extracts the `.egg` file:

```py
# main.py
import os
from utils import glue_extract_egg_file
glue_extract_egg_file()

logging.info(f"Python packages inside the egg file: {os.listdir('/tmp/packages')}")

# Output
# Updated sys.path with the package path: ['/tmp/packages', '[EGG FILE PATH].egg', ...]
# Python packages inside the egg file: ['boto3', 'botocore', ...]
```

But when importing a module, it uses the package inside the `.egg` file and not the extracted folder `/tmp/packages`:

```py
import boto3
print(f"Using boto3 file: {boto3.__file__}") 
# Outputs: /[EGG FILE PATH].egg/boto3/__init__.py
```

For some odd reason, pasting the lines as is from the function works:

```py
# main.py

# extract the egg file directly
package_path = "/tmp/packages"
# logic to extract the egg file
sys.path.insert(0, package_path)
logging.info(f"Updated sys.path with the package path {package_path}: {sys.path}")

import boto3
print(f"Using boto3 file: {boto3.__file__}") 
# Outputs: /tmp/packages/boto3/__init__.py
```

I found this behaviour to be *extremely* odd. Essentially, pasting the lines from the function `glue_extract_egg_file` works but calling the function doesn't work even though the PYTHONPATH is modified using `sys.path`.

How can I modify the import order properly with `sys.path` to import `boto3` inside `/tmp/packages` folder?

Comment: Is your `import boto3` in the same process as the one where you appended to `sys.path`?

Comment: Yes! It is in the /tmp/packages folder which gets inserted at the beginning of sys.path

Comment: That's where the files are.  I'm asking if you ran a script that called `glue_extract_egg_file`, then ran *another* script that calls `import boto3`. Changes to `sys.path` do not persist between processes.

Comment: I've also had problems when trying to use `sys.path`. My best solution was just to move everything (symbolic link) to a child directory and call the path explicitly. Clunky but no pathing issues.

Comment: I see, it's exactly as shown in the `main.py` file, I import the function `glue_extract_egg_file` in the `config.py` and run this function in the `main.py` file, test to make sure the `sys.path` is updated by logging it to the console, and then import `boto3` but it uses the wrong order :/

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ghoti, I could call the path directly but I have many imports later on and this would be a pain for maintaining in the future, I'd like to extract the `.egg` file into the folder `/tmp/packages` and use the python packages in this folder.

Comment: Couldn't you just create a symbolic link of `/tmp/packages`? Shouldn't have any problems maintaining it that way.